# What are the objects that are visible from a city?

Tags: amateur-observing

I live in a light polluted city of the northern hemisphere and I would like to know what I can see with my Skywatcher BK 707AZ2. I have already seen Jupiter (and its moons), Saturn, Mars, M45, the Double cluster, M42 and, obviously, the Moon.

M31, M13 and maybe M33 are also probably visible, but what else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

M6, the Butterfly cluster, and M7, the Ptolemy cluster,  are open clusters in the Scorpius constellation. They are interesting amateur target to observe.

M4, a globular cluster, is a very interesting object too. It is one of the brightest globular clusters. M4 is in the Scorpius cluster too.

I'm not sure about your location, but you should try observing M81 and M82. M82 is known as the Cigar galaxy. Both messier objects are galaxies. They could be tricky to find but they are worth the try.

Happy observations and clear skies :)

Comment: M6 and M7 are not visible visible for me (the tail of Scorpius is near the horizon), but M4 is a good target. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

We can't know this without knowing what the sky is like for your city. However, you can [determine what the limiting magnitude](http://www.imo.net/visual/major/observation/lm) is for your location, then you can set planetarium software to only display catalogued stars that are brighter than this limit. You can do this for naked eye objects, but you could also do this using your telescope to find the limiting magnitude for your equipment also.